# initialize to false ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

im trying to initialize each ticket to false after its created but im not sure how to do it

```
  def addToTicket
  ticket = Ticket.find_by(table: session[:table_id])
  if (ticket.nil?) || (ticket.tstatus == 9)
    ticket = Ticket.create(table: session[:table_id], tax: 0, tstatus: 0 )  

    session[:ticket] = ticket
    puts("**********Ticket created************")
  end
     ticket.orderItems.create(
            item: (Menuitem.find_by(name: params[:item_name]).id),
            ingredients: params[:good_ingredients],
            notes: params[:notes],
            istatus: 0
        )
        session[:ticket] = ticket
        puts("**************Ticket added to***********")
        calcTotal
        redirect_to guest_path

end
```

Comment: Which field you want to make false? could you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: session[:ticket] = ticket

Comment: You are creating a ticket and `session[:ticket] = ticket` this just means you're putting the newly created ticket in the `session`. So, I am still not sure what you meant by initializing to false?

Comment: By definition, you can't *initialize* an object to anything *after* it is created.

Comment: but in session[:ticket] you assign the newly created ticket.

Comment: Did you by any chance mean that you have some kind of status field in the tickets table and you want to make that false once the ticket is created? If that's the case, you can make that column `false` by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
session[:tickets] = {}
session[:tickets][ticket] = false
```

Comment: Why not `session[:tickets] = {ticket => false}`?